# Position of Div

Tags: html, css

Hi This is my css and html code. There are a few div. When browser size is maximum there is no problem but when i change browser size smaller then  div postion changed. For example : `<div id="cnrht"> id "cnrht" İçeriği Buraya Gelecek</div>` is on right of page but when browser goes smaller it is going to under other div and on left. How can i edit it.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Başlıksız Belge</title>
<style type="text/css">

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html { height:100%;
width:100%;}
body {
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 75%;
line-height: 1.5em;
height:100%;
width:100%;

}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: thin solid #F00;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
#container {
    border: thin dotted #006;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    background-color: #993;
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#contain {
    background-color: #9F6;

    width: 100%;


}
#cnlft {
    background-color: #C69;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
    float:left;
}
#cncnt {
    background-color: #F00;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
}

#cnrht {
    background-color: #0FF;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
}

.clr {clear:both;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">id "wrapper" İçeriği Buraya Gelecek</div>
    <div id="contain">
      <div id="cnlft">id "contain" İçeriği Buraya Gelecek</div>
      <div id="cncnt"> id "cncnt" İçeriği Buraya Gelecek</div>
      <div id="cnrht"> id "cnrht" İçeriği Buraya Gelecek</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I use like this it is work but i dont want use it: with:20%

Comment: Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Do i Have to use? If no way i can use

Comment: @user1508831 create a new question if you want to ask another question do not change this one

Comment: i know but they banned me , i couldn't add new questin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a minimum width to the containing element

```
#contain {
    background-color: #9F6;
    min-width: 1120px;/*sum of all the widths of its children*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/E5MFm/)

Answer (score 0):

You must set width of container in px, or to set width of child elements in %. Because, when user make his browser window smaller (or monitor resolution), if container width is expressed with %, container will decrease, and if container width is expressed with px, container width will stay the same, only sliders will be add to the window, so users must slide now to  see all content.

If you want one element to be adaptive to user window (resolution), all other elements must be adaptive as well.

There is min-width CSS property, but it will add sliders too, if user browser window (or resolution) is smaller than min-width value :)

Comment: i want width of container same with full page. what must be width of container?

Comment: could you please tell width of wrapper , container , header anc contain?

Comment: Well, like musa said, 1120px, becouse that is width of all children elements.